# Increase number by value specified by selected radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button, counting, selected

I would like to be able to set a bet on an item by a specific amount. The amount is specified by checking a radio button. Each click should add the selected amount to the total of that item and display it next to it. I am not sure if I'm going in the right direction but any help is appreciated! Thanks!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jvc6qbd/1/)

HTML

```
<form id="bet-form">
  <input type="radio" name="bet-placed" id="bet-1" value="1" checked>
  <label for="bet-1" class="bet-label">1</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="bet-placed" id="bet-5" value="5">
  <label for="bet-5" class="bet-label">5</label>
</form>

<section>
  <img class="count-this" src="some-img-1.jpg" />
  <span class="number">0</span>
</section>
<section>
  <img class="count-this" src="some-img-2.jpg" />
  <span class="number">0</span>
</section>
<section>
  <img class="count-this" src="some-img-3.jpg" />
  <span class="number">0</span>
</section>
```

jQuery

```
var clicks = 0;
var savedBet;

$('#bet-form input').on('change', function getBet() {
  savedBet = $('input[name=bet-placed]:checked', '#bet-form').val();
});

getBet();

$(".count-this").click(function() {
  clicks += $(savedBet);
  $(this).next().find(".number").innerHTML = clicks;
});

if (clicks == 0) {
  $(this).find(".number").css('display', 'none');
} else {
  $(this).find(".number").css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Not intuitive what you are trying to do in demo. You have 3 images (items) but only one set of radios. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomjerry25/0k4t4bkd/1/)

```
var textVal = 0;
var savedBet = 1; 

$('#bet-form input').on('change', function getBet() {
  savedBet = parseInt($('input[name=bet-placed]:checked', '#bet-form').val()); 
});


//getBet(); undefined class

$(".count-this").click(function() {

  textVal =  parseInt($(this).siblings('.number').text());
  textVal += savedBet;
  $(this).siblings('.number').text(textVal);

});

if (clicks == 0) {
  $(this).find(".number").css('display', 'none');
} else {
  $(this).find(".number").css('display', 'block');
};
```

Next time make sure to convert the `text` you're selecting by using `parseInt()`.

You need to declare `var textVal` to get the current value of the selected image then `add` it to the value of the `radio-button`.

Comment: I have checked it, but couldn't get it to work, thank you so much!